# Can't add multiple google maps in one page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

This is my entire code, and I don't know why it doesn't work. I  know that this question was asked before, but I still haven't found the solution to this code. I need to put multiple google maps... I can do it with one, however when I try to initialize more, it does not work:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Best Bikeparks</title>
    <style>
    html, body {
    height:100%
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    #map1 {
    width: 175px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    }
    #map2 {
    width: 175px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    }
    #map3 {
    width: 175px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map1"></div>
    <div id="map2"></div>
    <div id="map3"></div>
    <script>
    function initialize() {
    var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(39.630159,-84.175937);
    var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(33.677705,-117.852974);
    var myLatlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.520614,-0.121825);
    var mapOptions1 = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng1,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: 0
    }
    var mapOptions2 = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: 0
    }
    var mapOptions3 = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: 0
    }
    var map1= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'),mapOptions1);
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'),  mapOptions2);
    var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map3'), mapOptions3);

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng1,
    map: map1,
    title: 'Herastrau'
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng2,
    map: map2,
    title: 'Insbruck'
    });      
    var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng3,
    map: map3,
    title: 'Blala'
    });
    }  
    </script>


    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= MyAPI">
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid. You have 2 div's with the same ID, could be throwing things off. Try fixing that see if that resolves the problem. Also, you're including the API script twice, that's not necessary and could potentially also cause your script to misbehave.

Comment: Thank's but still the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the reference to the google maps javascript file on line 3 (you're adding it at the bottom) and change your api key reference to have the call back "&callback=initialize"

```js
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initialize"></script>
```